# Subsetting data.frame based on temporal proximity to a fixed -time WITHIN a condition

Tags: r

It is the very first time I can't manage to find a solution to my problem all by myself, using R code suggested in already existing posts. So thank you to all helpers for all the help I got so far.

---

**The design:**

I have a big `data.frame` (~3.7 million rows x 15 columns; let's call it `df`) looking like this (to make it more clear I kept only essential columns in the example):

```
       Site        Date Type  Mesure   .... 
 1   1590041 1998-05-15    P    0.15
 2   1590041 1999-05-04    P    0.18
 3   1590041 2000-05-16    C     3.6
 4   1590041 2001-05-15    I    2.10
 5   1590041 2002-04-17    P    4.30
 6   1590041 2003-09-03    I    0.20
 7   1700224 1999-12-15    P    0.19
 8   1700224 1999-05-08    P    2.12
 9   1700224 2000-05-12    C     1.6
10   1700224 2001-05-15    I    3.10
11   1700224 2003-08-19    P    0.30
12   1700224 2003-09-03    I    2.20
....
```

For each site I have samples being `Type = "C"`, `Type = "I"` or `Type = "P"`.
`Type = "C"` acts like a reference in my data set. Most of the time I have only 1 sample of `Type = "C"` for each Site (with a few exceptions having 2 samples of `Type = "C"`).

I would like to find, for each `Type="C"`-sample in my `data.frame`, the closest (using `Date`) `Type="I"` and the closest `Type="P"` samples, but coming from the same `Site`.

The final objective is to subset my initial `data.frame` by keeping all the `Type="C"` samples but only the `Type="P"` and `Type="I"` samples being the closest to a `Type="C"` sample from the same station.

With the help of a colleague we wrote:

```
 c1 <- df[df$Type=="C",]  
 p1 <- df[df$Type=="P",]  
 i1 <- df[df$Type=="I",]
```

---

```
toto <- by(df, df$Site, FUN = function(y)  
  t(as.data.frame(sapply(y[y$Type == "C", "Date"], function(x) 
    y[y$Type == "P", ][which.min(abs(difftime(x, y[y$Type == "P", "Date"]))), ]))))
```

---

```
head(toto)
$`1590041`
       Site        Date   Type   Mesure   
V1 "1590041" 1246406400    "P"     0.18       

$`1700224`
       Site        Date   Type   Mesure 
V1 "1700224" 1282694400    "P"     2.12  
...
```

---

Then I repeat the operation for `toto2` being similar to `toto` but changing `type = "P"` for `type= "I"`.

It is not exactly what I am looking for, but I didn't find a way to come closer to my expectations (at least, the code returns the correct `Type="P"` rows). 
My problems (I don't mean I expect my code to produce something else, just I would like to improve these following points):

- The result is a list (I can still `rbind` it later)
- I can't find a way to do the search for the closest `Type=P`-sample and `Type=I` sample at the same time (i.e. in a single function; currently, I repeat the same procedure 2 times)
- I got "silly" format for `Date`, and don't understand why.
- More important: I am, with this code, asking for results by `site`. It will not work for sites having 2 `Type=C` -samples (few cases). I would rather ask for results `Type="C"` sample, but then it means adding a condition in the code for looking at `Type="P"` and `Type="C"` samples from the same `Site`.

---

Ideally, the code would return something like this:

```
        Site       Date Type  Mesure   .... 
 2   1590041 1999-05-04    P    0.18
 3   1590041 2000-05-16    C     3.6
 4   1590041 2001-05-15    I    2.10
 8   1700224 1999-05-08    P    2.12
 9   1700224 2000-05-12    C     1.6
10   1700224 2001-05-15    I    3.10
```

I have to admit that I am already a little bit lost with all the `(`, `{`, `[`, etc... 
If anyone has some advice for subsetting my big `data.frame` and keeping only the selected rows (i.e. closest to a `Type="C"` sample of the same `Site`), I would be grateful.

Comment: Something is wrong with `1999-13-15` on row 7...

Comment: You're right Molx. I change it right away. The data showed in my post are "fake" data, i didn't notice this mistake when i created the sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example where `dplyr` makes things a lot easier:

```
df <- read.table(text="       Site        Date Type  Mesure 
 1   1590041 1998-05-15    P    0.15
 2   1590041 1999-05-04    P    0.18
 3   1590041 2000-05-16    C     3.6
 4   1590041 2001-05-15    I    2.10
 5   1590041 2002-04-17    P    4.30
 6   1590041 2003-09-03    I    0.20
 7   1700224 1999-12-15    P    0.19
 8   1700224 1999-05-08    P    2.12
 9   1700224 2000-05-12    C     1.6
10   1700224 2001-05-15    I    3.10
11   1700224 2003-08-19    P    0.30
12   1700224 2003-09-03    I    2.20", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)

library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>% group_by(Site) %>%  
  mutate (Diff = abs(difftime(Date, Date[Type=="C"], units="days"))) %>% 
  group_by(Site, Type) %>% 
  filter(Diff == min(Diff)) %>%
  select(-Diff)

df2
#     Site       Date Type Mesure 
#1 1590041 1999-05-04    P   0.18
#2 1590041 2000-05-16    C   3.60
#3 1590041 2001-05-15    I   2.10 
#4 1700224 1999-12-15    P   0.19 # Your expected result was wrong for this line
#5 1700224 2000-05-12    C   1.60
#6 1700224 2001-05-15    I   3.10
```

`df2` is created by grouping the data by `Site`, creating a new column with the absolute difference between the Dates and the Date of `Type == C`, then grouping by both `Type` and `Date`, and filtering only for the smaller difference for each `Type` of each `Site`.

This does not solve your duplicated `Type C` problem, since you did not specify which one you'd like to select (or at least use as reference). If you have that information, then the code can be updated. For example, if you use `min(Date[Type=="C"])` inside `difftime` you'll use the oldest `Date`, but you can also use `Date[Type=="C"][1]` to select the first ocurrence of `Type C`. In both cases, only one `Type C` will be kept, to keep both you'd also have to tweak the `filter` call.

Comment: Molx, your solution worked perfectly after few tweaks for use on my large dataset. I really appreciate your detailed explanation.   
Sites with more than 1 Type="C" sample generate error message:  
    Warning message:
    In unclass(time1) - unclass(time2) :
      longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length  
  
It works well when specifying min(Date[Type="C]). 

I will now try to work on the filter for keeping all the Type="C" samples.

Answer (score 1):

```
sp <- sapply(unique(df$Site), function(X) which(df$Site == X & df$Type == 'P')
      [which.min(abs(difftime(df[df$Site== X & df$Type == 'C',]$Date, 
      df[df$Site== X & df$Type == 'P',]$Date)))])

si <- sapply(unique(df$Site), function(X)  which(df$Site == X & df$Type == 'I')
     [which.min(abs(difftime(df[df$Site== X & df$Type == 'C',]$Date, 
     df[df$Site== X & df$Type == 'I',]$Date)))])

sc <- which(df$Site %in% unique(df$Site) & df$Type == 'C')

df[sort(c(sp, si, sc))]

#    Site       Date Type Mesure
#2  1590041 1999-05-04    P   0.18
#3  1590041 2000-05-16    C   3.60
#4  1590041 2001-05-15    I   2.10
#7  1700224 1999-12-15    P   0.19
#9  1700224 2000-05-12    C   1.60
#10 1700224 2001-05-15    I   3.10
```

`sp` contains the row numbers of the rows of type `P` which are closet in date to `C` at the same `Site`

Comment: germcd, as expected, sites with 2 Type="C" samples generated error messages (same issue as with Molx' solution). This can be solved with some small changes on the code. Although it requires the installation of dplyr package, I like the solution proposed by Molx: with no intermediate objects and no repeated procedure (the sapply). I find the the "single- command" from Molx more elegant (personal opinion of course).

Comment: @SimonN Molx's solution is nicer, if you put the procedure in another `sapply` on the type  you don't need to repeat it.